# background-image does not go 100% to the right

Tags: html, css

So my problem is i need my navbar background-image to go the entire distance of the page width wise. here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/faytAlvein/FDVby/4/
the black under the nav is fine ignore that. that's not there in the original because it's a different background image. just the width is the problem. it needs to scale 100% of the page no matter the window size. real background image is 1145x144 if that helps.

```
    <div id="navbar" >
        <div id="links" >
            <a href="thisindexpage.php" class="navLink" >Home</a>
            <a href="aboutUs.html" class="navLink" >About Us</a>
        </div>
    </div>​
```

navbar.css

```
#navbar
{
background-image: url('../images/nav.png');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-color: black;
}

#links
{
font-size: 20px;
font-family: helvetica;
padding-top: 25px;
padding-bottom: 94px;
margin-left: 150px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could "stretch" your background image to 100%, using the [`background-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/background-size) property.

```
background-size: 100%;
```

Your CSS:

```
#navbar {
   background-image: url('../images/nav.png');
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-color: black;
   background-size: 100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FDVby/7/

Comment: dunno how i missed that while i was google searching but that'll do it. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use the background-size property
Here's the documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/background-size